# plpgsql how to insert results of query into table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query `A` returning values `integer, numeric, integer`.
and a table `B`:

```
   (id integer,
    weight numeric,
    price integer
    )
```

the query returns many rows. I want to insert those rows directly to `B`. `B` doesn't have nor need a `PK`...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func()
  RETURNS void AS

$BODY$
begin

      query A
      insert to B?

      continue function operation
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I know it something like:

```
for row in query A
loop insert into B
```

but I can't find the proper syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
insert into b(id, weight, price)
    select id, weight, price  -- or whatever the column names are
    from A;
```

The syntax of `insert . . . select` doesn't change because you are in a function.